# Configuration of vtk in Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, vtk

I've installed **vtk** from [vtkpython-6.3.0-Windows-64bit.exe](http://www.vtk.org/download/) in `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0` of my computer. Then I add `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin` to my Path and       `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin` as well as `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages` to my PYTHONPATH in system variables. When I run `IDLE (Python GUI).exe` of Python and input `import vtk`,it shows:

```
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import vtk
  File "C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py",   line 39, in <module>
    from vtkCommonCore import *
ImportError: No module named 'vtkCommonCore'
>>>
```

What mistake did I make?

Please help me of this.

Comment: Please post the text of your error message (not an image).

Comment: It looks like VTK embeds Python. Is running it through a system Python actually supported?

Comment: @eryksun :Sorry,what do you mean by a system Python? I installed WinPython in my computer , Windows system. I think vtk can work on Python,but I don't know what mistake I've made.

Comment: By embed I mean it looks like there should be an executable in the `bin` directory that links with pythonXY.dll (e.g. python27.dll), probably located in the same directory, and looks for a  standard library (possibly modified) in `bin\Lib`, with VTK packages installed under `bin\Lib\site-packages`. I'm not saying it can't be used the way you want to. This is just a passing observation, plus I'm wondering why you're not using it as a standalone package.

Comment: @eryksun: Well, my tutor asked me to use Python 3 to generate sea surface with VTK library. I'm sorry that my English is very poor, so I can't understand what you mean clearly :( Thank you very much for your instruction.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you set the environment variables correctly? For example , be careful with quotes (aka don't put them).

I installed VTK 7 in Y instead that in program files (probably not a good choice since the built in vtkpython doesn't work), and the following setting for me works:

```
C:\Users\lib>set PATH=Y:\VTK 7.0.0-RC2\bin;%PATH%

C:\Users\lib>set PYTHONPATH=Y:\VTK 7.0.0-RC2\bin\Lib\site-packages

C:\Users\lib>python -c "import vtk;print vtk.__file__;print vtk.vtkVersion().GetVTKVersion()"
Y:\VTK 7.0.0-RC2\bin\Lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.pyc
7.0.0
```

In case of problems, try to add also `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages\vtk` to PATH (there are dlls in it as well)

Comment: I'm not sure. I did nothing with the user variables, but add `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin`    `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages`  `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages\vtk` to both PATH and PYTHONPATH . But it still doesn't work. Should I download `cmake` or something? I saw this on the internet,it says Visual Studio is needed,but I just want to use vtk in WinPython of my computer.@lib

Comment: Are you using ; to separate the paths? Cmake and visual studio are needed to compile vtk on you own, so in your case it's not necessary

Comment: Yes, I used ; to seperate .

Comment: By the way, PYTHONPATH did not exist in my system variables before,but I new PYTHONPATH by myself and add the words in it.

Comment: After I add `C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages\vtk` to PATH and PYTHONPATH ,the error change to this :`import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import vtk
  File "C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from vtkCommonCore import *
  File "C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages\vtk\vtkCommonCore.py", line 1, in <module>
    from vtkCommonCorePython import *
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_vtkCommonCorePython)`

Comment: can you clean the variables (remove vtk from the path) and run my instructions in a command prompt? maybe the error comes from the order in PATH

Comment: OK, but which folder should I enter, there isn't a `Lib` in the folder `User` in my computer as your instructions above. My command prompt is like this : `C:\Users\Dell>` Should I just run the instructions in this path? Sorry that I'm a new fish:(

Comment: yes, C:\Users\lib is my prompt. Actually the path doesn't matter, what you are doing is just setting environment variable in the current command prompt session

Comment: `E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64>set Path=C:\Program Files\VTK 6.3.
0\bin;%Path%

E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64>set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\VT
K 6.3.0\bin\Lib\site-packages

E:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64>python -c "import vtk;print vtk.__
file__;print vtk.vtkVersion().GetVTKVersion()"
  File "<string>", line 1
    import vtk;print vtk.__file__;print vtk.vtkVersion().GetVTKVersion()
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ` This is what it shows after I did. How annoying:(

Comment: When I run the instructions in `C:\Users\Dell>` it says `python is not an internal or external command`. So I move to the path where WinPython is installed.

Comment: I am not sure that vtk 6 supports python 3 . Have you considered python 2? have a look also at other Canopy/Anaconda https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/anaconda-the-creme-de-la-creme-of-python-distros-3/

Comment: Well, my tutor asked me to use Python 3 to generate sea surface with `Matplotlib` , `OpenGL` , `VTK` . I have already done with the first two libraries, but blocked by vtk . I have to figure it out ,or I cannot finish the mission that my tutor gave to me.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

After having the same problem, I gave in and installed the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) python distro. Anaconda has [VTK](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/vtk) all packaged for download and ready to go. Remember that VTK supports python 2.7.

Edit:
Apparently VTK now [supports python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184009/install-vtk-with-anaconda-3-6)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 32bit or 64bit version of Python?

VTK seems to be only available for 64bit python installation under Windows. If you can, try installing the 64bit version of Python instead of the 32bit version.

The default download from python.org seems to be the 32bit version of Python.