# Install VTK with anaconda 3.6

Tags: anaconda, vtk, conda, mayavi

I need to install VTK and mayavi on Ubuntu 16. I have Anaconda with Python 3.6. If I run:

```
conda install -c menpo vtk=7.0.0 vtk
```

I get:

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .


    UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
      - python 3.6*
      - vtk 7.0.0* -> python 3.5* -> openssl 1.0.1*
      - vtk 7.0.0* -> python 3.5* -> xz 5.0.5
    Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Apparently, I need Anaconda with Python3.5, but it's not availabe. Any idea? :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use this: https://anaconda.org/clinicalgraphics/vtk
The VTK is the 7.1.0 ones and was built to python 3.6 ;D

EDIT: Nowadays the anaconda repository has the latest version (8.1.1)

The code to do that is:

```
conda install -c anaconda vtk
```

Comment: This call was also perfectly working for me - Windows 10(64)! :-)

Answer (score 5):

I don't have ubuntu to try, but is seems that you are using a channel that does support linux  https://anaconda.org/menpo/vtk/files (for python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5)

Do you need that specific python, openssl and xz version? Otherwise create a new enviroment and let anaconda sort out the version compatibility

```
conda install -n envA -c menpo vtk=7 python=3
```

or if you want to be more specific:

```
conda install -n envB -c menpo vtk=7 python=3.5
```

or (if you are fine with python 2 and vtk 6 you can use the vtk package from the conda distribution)

```
conda install -n envC vtk python=2
```

Comment: This works for me, just use: 
```conda install -c menpo vtk=7```