# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'

Tags: python, pip

I am having problems when handling pyvista, it does not recognize the "vtk" module, I have tried to install it through the cmd of but it does not allow me since it generates an error, what can I do?

```
    import pyvista as pv
  File "C:\Users\DUVAN PACHECO\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyvista\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pyvista.plotting import *
  File "C:\Users\DUVAN PACHECO\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyvista\plotting\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .export_vtkjs import export_plotter_vtkjs, get_vtkjs_url
  File "C:\Users\DUVAN PACHECO\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyvista\plotting\export_vtkjs.py", line 55, in <module>        
    import vtk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'
```

any ideas?, I am using python 3.8.6

Comment: If you ever again face this kind of problem just do this - `pip install <MODULE>`. In your case just `pip install vtk`. And if you use python 3 then `pip3 install vtk`.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997436/configuration-of-vtk-in-python-in-windows

Comment: When trying to install the module, I get this: Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk

Answer (score 0):

You can go on PyPi and find the correct installing command for VTK. Here is the link:[PyPi](https://pypi.org)

Comment: ok the command is pip install vtk I checked it

Comment: When trying to install the module, I get this: Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk

Comment: In general VTK tries to be as portable as possible; the specific configurations below are known to work and tested.

VTK supports the following C++11 compilers:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 or newer
gcc 4.8.3 or newer
Clang 3.3 or newer
Apple Clang 5.0 (from Xcode 5.0) or newer
Intel 14.0 or newer
VTK supports the following operating systems:

Windows Vista or newer
Mac OS X 10.7 or newer
Linux (ex: Ubuntu 12.04 or newer, Debian 4 or newer)

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you're experiencing when trying to install the module? We cannot help you if you do not include it.

This command should work: `pip install vtk`

If not, I would recommend researching the error it is giving you.

Comment: when trying to install the module, I get this:                                                       
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you do not have that module installed. You can install it using

```
pip install vtk
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd verify that your install of Python is 64-bit.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966396/3369879

When running `python` you should see something like `[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`, where `64 bit (AMD64)` indicates you're running 64-bit Python.

Reason why I say this is because VTK only has Python 64-bit wheels and it's common in Windows to accidentally download and install Python 32-bit.  This is why you're getting:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk
```

It's because there are no VTK wheels for 32-bit Python.